# Trouble with nesting in sass

Tags: css, sass

I know you can add a parent selector like this:

```
.main-selector {
   .parent-selector & {

   }
}
```

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to go back to the .main-selector so I can add a hover state style to a child element. So, something like this:

```
.main-selector {
   .child-selector {
      *styles*
      .main-selector:hover & {
         *hover styles*
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: wait. so do you want the hover on the child element or the parent?

Comment: On the child elements, but the hover listener will be on the parent.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax would be:

```
.main-selector {
   .child-selector {
       *styles*
   }
   &:hover {
       *hover styles*
   }
}
```

This will produce a hover for your `main-selector`. You could do it the other way arround, like so:

```
.main-selector {
    &:hover {
        *hover styles*
    }
    .child-selector {
        *styles*
    }   
  }
```

Comment: That is what I was afraid of. I was hoping to avoid having 3 blocks of styles for the child elements, (normal, hover, and active) and wanted to nest the different states with the normal child element styles.